# Marshalling complex struct from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke

For a few days now I have been trying to Marshal a complex struct from C++ to C#, basically I have managed to get most of what I am trying to achieve done but now I'm stuck trying to marshal what I believe is a list.

In example I will include what I do get working and where I am stuck.

```
public: void __thiscall TransactionModule_t::GetTransaction(class Identity_t const &)const
```

Conformed as follwoing:

```
// public: void __thiscall TransactionModule_t::GetTransaction(class Identity_t const &)const     
[DllImport("Transaction.dll", EntryPoint = "?GetTransaction@TransactionModule_t@@Identity_t@@@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
public static extern void GetTransaction(IntPtr iPtr,[Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Identity transaction);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[Serializable]
public class Identity
{
    public uint Id;
    public uint Type;

    public Identity(uint id = 0, uint type = 0)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Type = type;
    }
}
```

This is working just fine.

However I want to call a method which gives me the list.

```
public: void __thiscall TransactionModule_t::GetTransactions(class std::vector<class Identity_t,class std::allocator<class Identity_t> > &)const
```

And where i am getting stuck:

```
// public: void __thiscall TransactionModule_t::GetTransactions(class std::vector<class Identity_t,class std::allocator<class Identity_t> > &)const 
[DllImport("Transaction.dll", EntryPoint = "long mangled entry point", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
public static extern void GetTransactions(IntPtr iPtr,[Out] Transactions transactions);
```

I tried making a class that fits in between the two.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[Serializable]
public class Transactions
{
    public Identity Identity;
    public Identity[] List;
}
```

Is it even possible to call this method, am I missing something here?

Comment: Marshalling works when both parties can understand the structure and access mechanism of data which is passed back and forth. C# won't understand structure and access mechanism of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to call this method?

No it is not. You cannot supply a `std::vector` from C# code.

Realistically you are going to need a C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: This was what I was afraid of, its time for me to start study some C++ and try grasp what is going on.

So far as from what I have read a vector is a undefined array that can change in size and allocator is a pre defined sized array.

Comment: The point is that interop requires binary compatibility, and that's not possible for complex types like C++ classes. C++/CLI makes life easy.